# Cordova can't see android targets

Tags: cordova

,Hi, all.

I have the next error with cordova:

```
~$ cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at   the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: installed 
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

But at least one android target is exist:

```
~$ $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager list target
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-25"
     Name: Android API 25
     Type: Platform
     API level: 25
     Revision: 3
```

So, i don't understand what cordova wants from me.

OS: funtoo stable
Cordova: 6.5.0
Android-studio: 162.3871768

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383039/882410 helps

Comment: I thought so too, but no :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailing list reply that helps:

```
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android#6.2.2
```

After i do:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android#6.2.2
```

`cordova build` works. But `cordova requirements` and `cordova emulate android` show me error:

```
Error: android: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 1):

**This solution no longer works with the latest versions of Cordoba, as of 2018.**

I had the same issue, and it took me some time to figure it out. I'm using **ubuntu 16.04** with **Android Studio 2.3.1** and the latest **cordova** to date, and got the same issue. [I documented the solution here](http://www.gooditdad.com/collections/linux-windows-and-it/cordova-android-sdk-installed-but-doesn-t-find-android-targets-bug), but here is the short answer:

The Android SDK has changed the command `android`'s functionality for `avdmanager`, but cordova is still trying to use the first one when detecting the android targets. To fix it, locate the file:

`path_to_your_app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js`

and locate around the line ~249 the following:

`return tryCommand('android list targets --compact', msg)`

and change it for:

`return tryCommand('avdmanager list targets --compact', msg)`

And that's it! In my case, that was enough to fix the issue.

[cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova)

Comment: check_reqs.js hasn't this lines

Comment: This line does not exist in my check_reqs.js!  ..this answer needs updating.

Comment: I am following the steps and turns out , its not working.