# cordova Android requirements failed: "Could not find an installed version of Gradle"

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to build a Cordova Android project using the most recent tools. I followed the instructions [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/):

```
$ cordova create myApp com.myCompany.myApp myApp
$ cd myApp
$ cordova platform add android@6.2.1 --save
$ cordova requirements android --verbose
```

But the result is:

```
Running command: android list targets
Command finished with error code 0: android list,targets

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-25,android-23
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
Error: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
    at /usr/local/nodejs_next/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:401:45
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/nodejs_next/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/nodejs_next/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/nodejs_next/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/nodejs_next/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/nodejs_next/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find Gradle (not sure where that's supposed to be).

I've seen [reports](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12524) of issues with Cordova and Android SDK Tools 25.3, but this seems to be different, and I have 25.2.3 (see below).

I have the following (this is on CentOS 6.8):

```
$ cordova --version
6.5.0

$ node --version
v6.10.2

$ npm --version
3.10.10

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0

$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/usr/local/android-sdk

# I installed the Android SDK from here
# https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads
# under "Get just the command line tools"

$ /usr/local/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
Installed packages:
  Path                        | Version | Description                    | Location                    
  -------                     | ------- | -------                        | -------                     
  build-tools;23.0.3          | 23.0.3  | Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.3 | build-tools/23.0.3/         
  build-tools;25.0.2          | 25.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 | build-tools/25.0.2/         
  extras;android;m2repository | 47.0.0  | Android Support Repository     | extras/android/m2repository/
  extras;google;m2repository  | 46      | Google Repository              | extras/google/m2repository/ 
  patcher;v4                  | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher/v4/                 
  platform-tools              | 25.0.4  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/             
  platforms;android-23        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 23        | platforms/android-23/       
  platforms;android-25        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 25        | platforms/android-25/       
  tools                       | 25.2.3  | Android SDK Tools 25.2.3       | tools/
```

**UPDATE:**

It doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in Cordova's or Android's docs, but if you're using the Android command-line tools without Android Studio, you have to manually install Gradle. Once you do, and it's on your PATH, this error will go away.

An additional thing that was confusing me: in older versions of Android SDK tools, there was a Gradle wrapper script in `tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew`. This can also be used to install Gradle, but I found it easier to just install it manually. This seems to have been removed as of the latest version.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

## Solution for linux with apt-get (eg.: Ubuntu, Debian)

I have quite similar problem. I obtained error:

```
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studi
```

but without Exception. I solved it on Ubuntu by

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

I found also commands that allows install newest version of gradle in Ubuntu. It works only when first command is executed before (probably some dependecies are incorrect).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle-ppa
```

> https://wtanaka.com/node/8079

If it does not work, try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.5/bin
```

More info:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/915980/package-is-installed-and-is-not-detected-gradle/915993#915993

## For CentOS

Instruction of instalation `gradle` for CentOS is under this link

> https://gist.github.com/parzonka/9371885

### Update

Now I installing gradle by [sdkman](http://sdkman.io) it is something like nvm for node.

Install sdkman

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Install gradle

```
sdk install gradle 4.0.2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on Debian 9 stretch

Comment: While this works, it installs a second gradle in the system, which in turn installs OpenJDK. There is no need to add all this bloat to the system when there is already a gradle and JRE inside the Android Studio installation directory.

Comment: save my day !! thanks :) work perfectly on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS :)

Answer (score 43):

If you have android studio installed then you might want to try:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/<username>/android-studio/gradle/<gradle-4.0>/bin"
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! no extra dependencies and packages introduced

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Be aware that you might need to add +x permission to the gradle executable to regular users if Android Studio was installed as root. This was my case and the directory was '/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin' instead. [This answer down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45770080/813951) was also helpful for me.

Comment: On Mac It's somewhere like this `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.4/bin/`.

Answer (score 37):

For Windows:

-Download last version of Gradle (https://gradle.org/releases)

-Create a folder and unzip files (I use C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle)

-Copy the path with the bin directory included (C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle\bin)

-Set the path C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle\bin (in my exemple) to "Path Environment Variables"

Variable name "Path" and variable value "C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle\bin" for both: User Variable table and System Variables table

You may need to reopen the "Prompt commad line"

To test, type gradle in prompt.

Comment: I was also required to restart pc although it was added to PATH (and while it was working in cmd)

Comment: The thing that made the difference for me was as you wrote "for both" meaning having it in both User Variables and System Variables - thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I m using Cordova version 7.0.1 and Cordova android version is 6.2.3. I was facing the issue while performing android build. I m using only Cordova CLI and not using android studio at all.

The quick workaround for this issue before its official fixed in Cordova is as follows:

1. Look for `check_reqs.js` file under platforms\android\cordova\lib folder
2. Edit the else part of `androidStudioPath` variable null check in `get_gradle_wrapper` function as below:

**Existing code:**

> `else {
>           //OK, let's try to check for Gradle!
>           return forgivingWhichSync('gradle');
>       }`

**Modified code:**

> `else {
>           //OK, let's try to check for Gradle!
>           var sdkDir = process.env['ANDROID_HOME'];
>           return path.join(sdkDir, 'tools', 'templates', 'gradle', 'wrapper', 'gradlew');
>       }`

**NOTE:** This change needs to be done everytime when the android platform is removed and re-added

UPDATE: In my case, I already had gradle wrapper inside my android SDK and I dint find necessity to install gradle explicitly. Hence, I made this workaround to minimize my impact and effort

Comment: I think this gradlew in "templates" was removed in the more recent Android SDKs. So you may just have to install gradle manually (see my update to the original post).

Comment: @JW thanks for the info. but I installed latest version of android (SDK 25) and I had gradle wrapper. Not sure whether its part of old sdk's. Moreover this check fails only in recent Cordova version. So I worked it out the easier way for now as I dint find gradle necessity in my case

Comment: @JW. Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 7):

## macOS

Gradle can be added on the Mac by adding the line below to `~/.bash_profile`. If the file doesn't exist, please use `touch ~/.bash_profile`. This hidden file can be made visible in Finder by using `Command + Shift + .`

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin/
```

Use `source ~/.bash_profile` to load the new path directly into your current terminal session.

Answer (score 7):

## Windows 10 (with Android Studio installed)

With this solution, you don't have to install Gradle multiple times on your system.

1. Find Gradle installation folder: Go to `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists`. Pick a version (in my case `gradle-6.4-all`). Navigate further until you reach the 'bin' folder.
2. Add the path to the Path environment variable: Start menu > enter 'edit environment variables'. Look for the 'Path' variable in the lower section (system variable) and click 'Edit'. Then add as a new value the complete path, in my case `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.4-all\h8pi7famayzdg9sl28jayaip\gradle-6.4\bin`. Don't forget to save your changes!
3. Don't forget to restart all the terminals (e.g. restart VS Code). After that, it worked on my computer!

Answer (score 5):

I followed this **[Qiita](https://qiita.com/bathtimefish/items/576ea4103f1958772746)** tutorial to solve my trouble.

**Environment:** **`Cordova 8.1.1`, `Android Studio 3.2`, `cordova-android 7.0.0`**

1. Set **gradle** PATH into `.profile` file.

```
export PATH="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.6/bin":$PATH
```

2. Export the setting.

```
source ~/.profle
```

3. Now build cordova project.

```
cordova build android
```

PS: If `cordova-android@7.0.0` causes build error, downgrade your platform version to **6.3.0**.

Answer (score 4):

Extending https://stackoverflow.com/users/5540715/surendra-shrestha answer for linux (~mint) users:
1. Install [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?hl=es-419) (many tools have been deprecated for command line, so this is likely required). Asuming you follow the author instrucctions, your Android Studio will be installed in /usr/local/android-studio/. At the time of writing, the gradle version in Android Studio is 3.2, look at yours with `ls /usr/local/android-studio/gradle/`.
2. Add your gradle command, this can be done extending the PATH, as @surendra-shrestha suggested (should be written in ~/.bashrc to preserve the PATH change), adding an alias `echo 'export alias gradle=/usr/local/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`. Or making a symbolic link: `sudo ln -sn /usr/local/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle /usr/bin/gradle` (this was my choice).
3. Run `cordova requirements` to check everyhing is OK, should output something like:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19
Gradle: installed /usr/local/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle
```

Comment: The alias didn't work for me. The symbolic link worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: your tick is worked. after giving permission as following. sudo chmod -R 777 /home/<UserName>/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.10.1/bin/gradle

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that my android version was still on 6.1.2 which is not compatible with the newest Android Studio 2.3.1.

So what I did was run

`cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.2.1`

Comment: I had specifically added 6.2.1, so that's not my issue.

Comment: My bad @JW. Didn't notice that you mentioned using 6.2.1 in your Question.

Answer (score 2):

To answer OP's question:

Since you're on Linux you'll have to install gradle yourself, perhaps following [this guide](https://gradle.org/install#manually), and then put an entry in `PATH` to a folder that contains `gradle` executable.

Cordova has some code to look for gradle if you have Android Studio but only for Mac and Windows, see here:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/e13e15d3e9aa4b9a61c6ece434e7c023fa5c3553/bin/templates/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js#L101-L132

---

Semi-related to OP's question, as I'm on Windows.

After upgrading to `Android Studio 2.3.1`, `cordova@6.5.0`, `cordova-android@6.2.1` (node@4.7.3), I had build issues due missing target 25 and gradle.

First issue was solved with comment from X.Zhang (i.e. change `android` to `avdmanager`), BTW it seems a commit to fix that [has landed on github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commits/master) so cordova-android should fix that in 6.3.0 (but I didn't test).

Second issue was as follows:

The problem turned out to be that `process.env['ProgramFiles']` evaluates to  `'C:\\Program Files (x86)';` whereas I have Android Studio in `C:\\Program Files`.

So the quick hack is to either override this value, or install Android Studio to the other place.

```
// platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js

module.exports.get_gradle_wrapper = function() {
    var androidStudioPath;
    var i = 0;
    var foundStudio = false;
    var program_dir;
    if (module.exports.isDarwin()) {
        // ...
    } else if (module.exports.isWindows()) {
        // console.log(process.env['ProgramFiles'])';
        // add one of the lines below to have a quick fix...
        // process.env['ProgramFiles'] = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)';
        // process.env['ProgramFiles'] = 'C:\\Program Files';
        var androidPath = path.join(process.env['ProgramFiles'], 'Android') + '/';
```

I'm not sure what would be the proper fix to handle both folders in a robust way (other than iterating over both folders).

Obviously this has to be fixed in cordova-android project itself; otherwise whenever you do `cordova platform rm` your fixes will be gone.

I opened the ticket on Cordova JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12677

Comment: I had the issue on windows also because my android studio was installed in a different path. I corrected it adding a junction : `mklink /j  "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"  "C:\myactualpathto\Android Studio"`

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTION FOR Mac

Sample problem but I found my solution with brew.
1. Make sure you have the latest Android Studio installed.
2. Confirm from SDK manager that you have the required SDKs installed.
3. (optional)you could have an AVD installed as well.
4. install Homebrew.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

5. Then run brew update to make sure Homebrew is up to date.

```
brew update
```

6. Run brew doctor to make sure everything is safe

```
brew doctor
```

7. Add Homebrew's location to your $PATH in your .bash_profile or .zshrc file.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

8. If you don't have Node already installed, add:

```
brew install node
```

9. (Optional) To test out your Node and npm install, try installing Grunt (you might be asked to run with sudo)

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

10. Install Gradle

```
brew install gradle
```

Run: `cordova run android --device` with you device connected on a Mac and you have gradle working this time.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many but it didnt work finally ,

1. I installed gradle using macos port
2. I set GRADLE_HOME path as it told after installing gradle
3. I executed ::

`sudo chmod -R a+rwx /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines *`

`sudo chmod -R a+rwx *`

`sudo chmod 777 {your-gradle-path}`

It immediately started working

Answer (score 1):

same problem but very simple on Mac with brew:

- brew update
- brew install gradle

Answer (score 1):

Solution for linux and specifically **Ubuntu 20:04**. First ensure you have Java installed before proceeding:

```
1. java -version
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Open .bashrc

```
vim $HOME/.bashrc
```

Set Java environment variables.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
export JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre"
```

Visit [Gradle's website](https://gradle.org/releases/)  and identify the version you would like to install. Replace version **6.5.1** with the version number you would like to install.

```
 1. sudo apt-get update
 2. cd /tmp && curl -L -O https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
 3. sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
 4. sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle /tmp/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
```

To setup Gradle's environment variables use **nano** or **vim** or **gedit** editors to create a new file:

```
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
```

Add the following lines to gradle.sh

```
export GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle/gradle-6.5.1/"
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Run the following commands to make gradle.sh executable and to update your bash terminal with the environment variables you set as well as check the installed version.

```
1. sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
3. source /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh
4. gradle -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you installed the latest Android Studio 2.3.1, it changed command `android list targets` to `avdmanager list targets`, so there is how to fix it:

**add path `<android-sdk>/tools/bin` to `PATH`, this is for MacOX.**

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin"
```

**change your cordova project code `<your-cordova-project>/platforms/android/cordova/lib/android_sdk.js`**.

change

```
module.exports.list_targets_with_android = function() {
    return superspawn.spawn('android', ['list', 'targets'])
```

to

```
module.exports.list_targets_with_android = function() {
    return superspawn.spawn('avdmanager', ['list', 'targets'])
```

Comment: See above -- I'm not using Android Studio; just the command-line tools. But the `list_targets_with_android` function was helpful in debugging. It wasn't calling `android` correctly, due to a permissions issue, which I fixed. I still have the Gradle issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Update your cordova to the latest version and the issue should be resolved.
In case the issue not resolved please set the path in the environment variable (in case of Windows). Example:
System Variable 
Value name GRADLE_HOME
Value D:\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.3.1 (please replace with your path)

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gradle
```

This works for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Windows (Windows 10) is:

1. Make sure you have Java 8 installed
2. Download Gradle binary from https://gradle.org/install/
3. Create a new directory C:\Gradle with File Explorer
4. Extract and copy gradle-6.7.1 to C:\Gradle
5. Configure your PATH environment variable to include the path C:\Gradle\gradle-6.7.1\bin
6. Run gradle -v to confirm all is okay.
   C:>Gradle -v

---

### Gradle 6.7.1

Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24 UTC
Revision:     2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 x86

C:>

Finally, run [Cordova environments] to check that all is set for development.

C:\Users\opiyog\AndroidStudioProjects\IONIC\SecondApp>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-30,android-29,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-19
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-6.7.1\bin\gradle.BAT

Answer (score -2):

**“Android target: not installed”**

Please install Android target / API level: "android-25".

You need to create an Android Virtual Device (API level: "android-25" or latest) or need to add android real device.

Also you can import the project in Android Studio and run.

You can check here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: I don't think you should need a virtual device just to do the build. But anyway, I added one: `system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86`, and got the same error.