# Getting Gradle set up to work with Cordova on Arch Linux

Tags: android, cordova, maven, archlinux

I'm trying to bootstrap a Cordova project under Arch (kernel 4.10.10-1). I've got essentially no experience working with Cordova, so I'm mostly prodding around blindly right now.

I've tried just installing Cordova via `pacman -Sy cordova`. After `create`ing my project, `build`ing results in this:

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

... Which is pretty predictable. I've got no Android tooling installed.

After installing Android Studio and a number of SDKs for 5.0-7.0 and setting up my `$ANDROID_HOME` in `~/.zshrc`, I tried to `cordova build` again:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/me/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

And I'm a bit stumped by this. I'm admittedly pretty unfamiliar with Android Studio, but I can't find anything that would let me install Maven *through* Android Studio (I've tried installing Maven via `pacman` -- but that didn't really work out; the issue persists). I also haven't been able to find a lot of up-to-date documentation online.

I've also been able to systematically reproduce all of these steps when installing Cordova using `npm` rather than `pacman`.

How can I get around this Maven issue and get `cordova build` to behave properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the fact that cordova doesn't try to look for gradle in any linux OS [see here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/bin/templates/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js#L101-L132)

With that you can see that gradle must be available on your machine

[Here](https://gradle.org/install#manually)'s a guide on how to install it.

Check out [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523141/2350224), from where I got the info.

This is as far as I've reached and I'm yet to try installing gradle.