# Error when building android APK

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, meteor, android-gradle-plugin

I have Android-studio 2.3.2 (which is android-studio-ide-162.3934792-linux.zip) installed, which is the latest stable version. I am using fedora 24. I am using meteor 1.4.4.2

When I build an APK using "meteor build" I get this error:

> While building Cordova app for
>   platform Android: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK.
>   Might need to update your Android SDK. Looked here: ~/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

It seems to me the path to gradle wrapper has changed on the latest version of Android-studio. I don't have a previous version of Android-studio to prove this though. I've searched for previous versions of Android-studio and could not find them. I have searched for a solution but there is no one out there who seems to be solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz which installs version 25 or higher version by default solved the problem for me. Because I could not find a way to uninstall Android Studio I had to uninstall and re-install my linux.

See https://gist.github.com/rolandboon/0a5abe1d9c6c515c59ec for downloading and installing the sdk

Answer (score 0):

You will find a solution in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra) and some explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra#answer-43523141)

The explanation is that the linux version of cordova does not search for gradle in the Android studio install folders like for Windows (and even for windows it does not find it if android studion is not installed in c:\program files\android\android studio) or Mac .

On Linux (and maybe for Mac&Windows in future versions of Cordova), you have to install a version of gradle and add it to your path (way to install gradle depends on the version of Linux you're using)

The behaviour was different in the past because android sdk was not inside Android studio like it is now. You could find gradle in the ANDROID_HOME/tools folder.

With recent upgrades, Android SDK structure has changed and it is now part of android studio.