# An error occurred while running cordova platform add --save android (exit code 1)

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried to build the project or run the emulator it keeps saying this error.
/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
        throw err;
        ^

```
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
    '/home/jayzdevera/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
    You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
    at Object.get
    (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore
    (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new Insight
    (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:38:34)
    at Object.<anonymous>
    (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:37:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

I am new to Ionic 2. BTW I am using Ubuntu 16.04 OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a permission related issue. Try executing the following commands to resoleve the issue:

> sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
>
> sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config

Check out this [link](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262) for more info on this.

Comment: It worked! But theres another error that I've encounter when I try to run it on my android device with a usb cable here is the error:

Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio

But I think I can solve this btw thanks :) can I ask a question to you regarding to ionic 2? Sorry I am new to Ionic Framework and Mobile Development.

Comment: @JayzdeVera Glad it worked. For the other issue you mentioned in comment, either install gradle if you have not or else following the steps here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra/44592751#44592751 I dont have hands on experience in Ionic2. But will try my best to get you the answer. Cheers

Comment: Awesome. Thankyou so much!