# ionic cordova build android - failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

While trying to build the ionic app for the android platform I am getting the below error to install Android build tools , But I have configured sdkmanager in my PATH variable and ANDROID_HOME as well. Please help me on this.

System Variables :

%ANDROID_HOME% = K:/android-sdk
%PATH% = %APTH%/%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin

**Output of %ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list**

```
Available Updates:
  ID      | Installed | Available
  ------- | -------   | -------
  tools   | 26.0.1    | 26.1.1
done
```

Error :

```
[21:12:35]  lint finished in 4.37 s
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):


        (truncated) ... eLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
                at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
                at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
                at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)


        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Script 'K:\mobileApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line:
        64

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
        > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

Comment: I guess gradle path is not found in your case. Check out this link to see if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra/44592751#44592751

Comment: @Gandhi I have configured gradle in my System variables as well

Comment: may be you gotta install android build tool 19.1.0 or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your PATH variable to point to Android Platform Tools ie.

```
%PATH% = %PATH%/%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools
```

Hopefully this solves your Error !

Comment: @Lokkeshwaren , I have downloaded the sdk from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip and extracted it into folder called android-sdk. 
%ANDROID_HOME%=K:\android-sdk
%PATH%=%PATH%\%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin. I have configured like above.

Comment: also include a PATH till .../platform-tools - as given in Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check you Android Version in your **config.xml**

It should be something like :

```
 <engine
  name="android"
  spec="^6.2.3"/>
```

Comment: These are the configurations which I have<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="com-sarriaroman-photoviewer" spec="^1.1.10" />

Comment: Checkout the recent Answer