# Error ionic cordova build --release android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, apk

ionic cordova build --release android is failed.

my command failed with the error "cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1."

here is the screenshot of the error!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7E2T.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your PATH variable to point to Android Platform Tools

`%PATH% = %PATH%/%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools`

Have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622204/ionic-cordova-build-android-failed)

Answer (score 0):

I see that the image you tagged clearly says that you need to accept the User Agreements for SDK and install missing components. I am assuming you have freshly downloaded Android Studio or SDK. You need to fire Android Studio and accept user agreement and install the missing SDK components. You will need Android Build Tools and an API base framework to build the app.