# Cordova installation error

Tags: android, cordova

Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio

Although I have installed android-studio but is stored on my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have android studio installed then you might want to try:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/<username>/android-studio/gradle/<gradle-4.0>/bin"
```

[check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra)